# Topology space classification based on the induced Borel sigma algebra

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let's define that two measurable spaces $(\Omega_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\Sigma_2)$ are ${\it equivalent}$ if there exists a one-to-one and onto mapping $T:\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$, such that both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are measurable.

It is trivial to see that if both measurable spaces are the Borel $\sigma-$algebras of homeomorphic topological spaces, then they are equivalent. The converse is not true in general. For example,  $([0,1], {\cal B}([0, 1]))$ and  $((0,1), {\cal B}((0, 1)))$ are equivalent, but the original topologies are not homeomorphic.

My question:  Are $(\Bbb R, {\cal B}(\Bbb R))$ and $(\Bbb R^2, {\cal B}(\Bbb R^2))$ equivalent? ( I guess not) and more generally, are there some known results on topology space classifications based on the equivalence of the induced Borel $\sigma$-algebras?

Comment: What's your bijection $T\colon[0,1]\to(0,1)$?

Comment: @Brian: It's a classical theorem that any two uncountable Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic. (Which should also answer the question.)

Comment: @Asaf: Ahhh. OK. I was afraid it might for a questionable reason. And, yes, it answers the question, the first part anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Just cheked the Borel isomorphism theorem, kind of surprising to me.